# In React, why isn't my component styling being updated when the value of my variable changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have this React code which should apply an inline style of `textDecoration: 'line-through'` when `completed` is true:

```
import React from "react";

var x = false;
function strike() {
  x ? x = false : x = true;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={strike}
      style={x ? {textDecoration: "line-through"} : null}
    >
      Buy Bughattis
    </button>
  )
}
```

The line-through function not working in that it is not changing the text decoration as I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the issue is that you are creating a regular variable instead of a react useState object. Try this code instead:

```
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";

function App () {
  const [x, setX] = useState(false);
  return <button onClick={()=> {setX(x => !x)}} style={[your style as is]}>Buy Bughattis</button>
}

export default App;
```

also, whether or not this solves your problem, you should go read the link I shared in my comment on your post and fix this post up to follow the community guidelines, or delete this post.